# Extending the MongoDB Connect Class

Tags: php, oop, mongodb

I am looking to put a MongoDB connectiontion method into it's own class, but obviously new Mongo() is already a class, so how can I go about this?

```
    $conn = new Mongo;
    $db = $conn->thundergallery;
    $grid = $db->getGridFS();
    $file = $grid->findOne(array('unique_id' => $posted_id));
    echo $file->getBytes();
    exit;
    $conn->close();
}catch(MongoConnectionException $e){
    die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
}catch(MongoException $e){
    die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why you wouldn't just extend the Mongo class? class MyMongo extends Mongo {

Comment: Thats what I need to do, any idea how?

Comment: Worth reading [PHP Classes and Objects: The Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the class doing something like the following. If you need a hint at any deeper levels of implementation, please add that to your original question :)

```
class MyMongo extends Mongo {
    public function myMethod() {
        return 'whatever';
    }
}

$my_mongo = new MyMongo();
```